# Reactjs POST request using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to call a POST request in ReactJs using Axios, but getting an error. Code:

```
const payload =
        {
            device_id: 'ASDACCAS',
            device_type: 'Web',
            device_version: '1.2',
            device_user_id: 'ASDBADKKK1234AS'
        }
        axios({
                  method: 'post',
                  url: 'https://stageapi.myapi.com/v3_2/user/splash',
                  data: payload,
                  headers: {
                  'secret-key': 'mysecretkey',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
              })
```

But this is giving me error:

Failed to load https://stageapi.myapi.com/v3_2/user/splash: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.

Kindly help me whats wrong here. I am new to ReactJS and moving from mobile app development environment. I have been on this for so long, tried every method for axios POST including by appending formdata to body. Still the same.

EDIT:
Also, I am not sure if its something related to CORS. I have installed the the CORS plugin in chrome. Are there any changes that I need to make in API side code? Which is written in php.

Comment: "I have installed the the CORS plugin in chrome." — This doesn't support preflight requests.

Comment: "Are there any changes that I need to make in API side code?" — Yes, you need to respond to the preflgiht request with an OK status (and the right HTTP headers)

Comment: Thanks Quentin, it was indeed the issue with API side handling. I showed it to the backend guy and he fixed it. And as mentioned in the link provided by you, we removed the custom headers. Working fine now.

Answer (score -1):

```
     axios.post('https://stageapi.myapi.com/v3_2/user/splash', 
      payload,    
      headers: {
                'secret-key': 'mysecretkey',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             }           
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

When you want to make a post request, you need to stringify body request like this:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://stageapi.myapi.com/v3_2/user/splash',
    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: {
        secret-key': 'mysecretkey',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
})
```

Comment: Axios does that for you.

Comment: But I don't have the same experience with Axios in this. And I should stringify objects for each post requests that I want to send.